# Missing .dll when i try to create migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Something really weird happened to my today, i was trying to generate the migration file for my project (thing i have done many time before) but when i run the basic command "dotnet ef add migration ..." i have the error "build failed" , but without any error.

I though i was missing one dll ore something like that, so i did -v to see what was wrong and i figured out that i have more than 1000 errors and all of my dlls and namespaces are missing (like httpGet, or even AspNetCore for exemple).

The thing is that i can compile and run my project without any problems, and see my dlls in my local files but when i try to run the command it seems like everything is missing. I tryed almost everything like rebuilding my solution, updating entityFramework, and never get any errors.

So if you had the same error or maye have a solution it will really help me!

Dotnet version:3.1.407

EntityFramework core version:5.0.4

Comment: Do you use visual studio or the .NET CLI? Did you try removing the bin/obj folders and build again? Maybe try via the CLI, `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`.. tell us what the output there is.

Comment: @jpgrassi got no error when running those two commands, everything is up to date apparently, also tryed to remove those folders, and builded again, nothing changed

Comment: what is the problem then? Only when you run the `dotnet ef` commands? Do you have the ef tools installed? Which version? `dotnet ef --version`

Comment: seems like ef commands works, version returned is 5.0.5. I have everything installed but when i run the command add migration it returns my 1k+ errors of unknown namespace and dlls

Comment: Strange.. can you maybe share a screenshot? or text of the errors? And  you haven't changed anything in your project? Since you said you already added migrations in the past.. did you maybe move projects around?

Comment: just saw in my csproj that my project is trying to use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and design 5.0.4, but the version 5.0.5 is available. Maybe i should upgrade? i don't want to make things worse ...

Comment: Just do it.. can't get worse than now ;)

Comment: did not change anything unfortunatly... my errors are still the same, it can't find all my dlls and namespace using dotnet ef add migration..

Comment: Does your solution have other projects?Make sure they do not have error too. And when you build a new project, will you face the problem?